# IPv6 Global Multicast

Tags: networking, ipv6, multicast

Here is my interface configuration.

> inet6 addr: 2001:db8:0:f101::1/64 Scope:Global
>
> inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:feaa:c19e/64 Scope:Link

Link local works ok.

> ping6 -I eth0 ff02::1

But how can I test ipv6 global multicast?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address#Multicast

> ping6 -I eth0 ff0e::1

No results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "All hosts" group is only defined up to link-local scope, and the "All routers" group is only defined up to site-local scope. You got results with `ff02::1` because all hosts join it by default, whereas the global-scope address `ff0e::1` has no predefined purpose and hosts do not automatically join it.

You would need to use a program that actually asks the OS to join the multicast group (and responds to some sort of UDP-based ping query). You could use the IPv4-only [mtools](https://github.com/troglobit/mtools) as a starting point.

Aside from that, in practice most ISPs do not carry multicast between customers (and almost never between ISPs), so no matter what group scope you use, it will be limited to your network only.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for the reply. I need to join an IPv6 multicast group. Surely there must be a way to join multicast groups? Or what is the point in their existence?

Comment: Generally, the system as a whole has doesn't care about custom multicast groups – it is specific programs which do. So it's _those programs_ which must request the OS to join the multicast group that they want (e.g. VLC itself performs the join when you try to play a multicast video stream; Avahi performs the join when you ask it to use mDNS).